# Django import_export decode ascii code on submit?

Tags: python, django, csv, ascii, django-import-export

Im trying to upload and import data into models from a csv file that contains special ASCII characters, for example "Big Fish Äö√Ñ√¥s", the django import_export would give me an error that reads:

Imported file has a wrong encoding: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 511: invalid start byte.

This error would show when I select the file and click submit.

The feature Im trying to implement would take a csv file that contains thousands of row of data, I was wondering if there is a way that I can go through each row level and clean the data line by line.

I have tried implmenting the before_import_row method, but it doesn't seems to be called.

my admin.py:
'''ptyhon

```
from django.contrib import admin

from import_export.admin import ExportActionModelAdmin, enter code hereImportExportMixin, ImportMixin
from import_export.resources import ModelResource

from .forms import CustomConfirmImportForm, CustomImportForm
from .models import Author, Book, Category, Child, EBook


class ChildAdmin(ImportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


class BookResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Book

    def for_delete(self, row, instance):
        return self.fields['name'].clean(row) == ''


class BookAdmin(ImportExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ['categories', 'author']
    resource_class = BookResource


class CategoryAdmin(ExportActionModelAdmin):
    pass


class AuthorAdmin(ImportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
```

'''

my models.py

'''python

```
[![import random
import string

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    birthday = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def full_clean(self, exclude=None, validate_unique=True):
        super().full_clean(exclude, validate_unique)
        if exclude is None:
            exclude = \[\]
        else:
            exclude = list(exclude)
        if 'name' not in exclude and self.name == '123':
            raise ValidationError({'name': "'123' is not a valid value"})


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        unique=True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Book name', max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author_email = models.EmailField('Author email', max_length=75, blank=True)
    imported = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    published = models.DateField('Published', blank=True, null=True)
    published_time = models.TimeField('Time published', blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - child of %s' % (self.name, self.parent.name)


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_private = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Role(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)


class Person(models.Model):
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class WithDefault(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Default', max_length=75, blank=True,
                            default='foo_bar')


def random_name():
    chars = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(chars) for _ in range(100))


class WithDynamicDefault(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField('Dyn Default', max_length=100,
            default=random_name)


class WithFloatField(models.Model):
    f = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)


class EBook(Book):
    """Book proxy model to have a separate admin url access and name"""
    class Meta:
        proxy = True][1]][1]
```

'''
Here is the csv file, as you can see it contains weird characters.

[image]

[image]

and here is the error when i click submit:

[image]

ultimately, I'm wondering if there is a way that I can clean the data on each row when i click the submit button. It seems that import_export under the hood will throw an error message as soon as it sees that the files contains werid characters and not even hitting my code. Thank you.

Comment: I looked at the github issue page at https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/72, seems to be a similar issue, but doesn't seem to have a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

see that format xlxs does not get this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled the package and it worked for me.

```
pip3 uninstall django-import-export==2.3.0

pip3 install django-import-export==2.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug in the `django-import-export` version you are using. I had a similar issue with `django-import-export==2.8`. Upgrading it to `django-import-export==3.0.0b4` fixed the import issue as one of the maintainer suggested on this [thread](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/73).

if you want to keep working on your version you can alternatively use a python function code based on your defined `ModelResource` like this

```
from tablib import Dataset

book_resource = BookResource()
dataset=Dataset()
# encoding to fix the errors you may need to switch encoding
f= open("data_to_import.csv", encoding="utf8")
imported_data = dataset.load(f.read())
# import the csv in the DB
book_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)
f.close()
```